# Need help in implementing dynamic grid layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Please refer [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dbdg3067/14/) fiddle here to understand the problem I'm trying to explain. I want such a layout wherein divs will utilize all the available space. There are 8 divs here which are resizable. When I minimize divs `A` and `B`, an empty space is seen below these divs. I want divs `D` and `E` to occupy that empty space.

[image]

How can I achieve this? There are some jQuery plugins available like [gridstack](http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/) out there but their resizing feature is somewhat different. Without using any available jQuery plugin, is it possible to achieve mentioned effect? If you have any useful resources please share. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

One solution could be to have 3 columns in `.container` but this solution might not work if div is resized horizontally.

[image]

Comment: What if you put every item as "float" item with css? (the fiddle you give is not working... resizable not working at all - for me)

Comment: Note that your fiddle doesn't work properly as you haven't included jQueryUI: https://jsfiddle.net/dbdg3067/11/

Comment: Sorry, fiddle was not working. I've made appropriate changes. Please refer this link: https://jsfiddle.net/dbdg3067/14/

Answer (score 0):

You could try a 3 col solution (And use javascript to properly order the items in each column):

```css
.col {
  background: whitesmoke;
  width: 165px;
  float: left;
}
.item {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  background: grey;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.custom {
  height: 265px;
}
.custom2 {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item custom"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item custom2"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="item custom2"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item custom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was thinking of this solution but if divs are resized horizontally as well, this solution might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your div structure to the following I think that will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.tile').resizable({
        handles: 'e, s, se',
  containment: '.container'
    });
});
```

```css
.tile
{
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0% 0% 3% 0%;
    min-height: 20px;
    max-height: 360px;
    max-width: 540px;
    min-width: 180px;
    text-align: centre
}

.verticalspace{
    width:180px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0% 0% 0% 1%;
}

.container{
    overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class= "verticalspace">
        <div class="tile">A</div>
        <div class="tile">E</div>
    </div>
    <div class= "verticalspace">
        <div class="tile">B</div>
        <div class="tile">F</div>
    </div>
    <div class= "verticalspace">
        <div class="tile">C</div>
        <div class="tile">G</div>
    </div>
    <div class= "verticalspace">
        <div class="tile">D</div>
        <div class="tile">H</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this kind of structure will stay close even if somediv above it is collapsed also

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @ravi..!! The problem with your code is horizontal resize of div A is messed up. How can we avoid this?